# How to do product catalog building with MySQL and tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build a product catalog with data from several e-commerce websites. The goal is to build a product catalog where every product is specified as good as possible using leveraged data across multiple sources.

This seems to be a highly complex task as there is sometimes misinformation and in some cases the unique identifier is misspelled or not even present.

The current approach is to transform the extracted data into our format and then load it into a mysql database. In this process obvious duplicates get removed and I end up with about 250.000 datasets.

Now I am facing the problem on how to brake this down even further as there are thousands of duplicates but I can not say which as some info might not be accurate.

e.g.

```
ref_id | title | img | color_id | size | length | diameter | dial_id
```

this one dataset might be incomplete or might even contain wrong values.

Looking more into the topic, this seems to be a common use case for deep learning with e.g. tensorflow.

I am looking for an answer that will help me in order to create the process on how to do that. Is tensorflow the right tool? Should I write all datasets to the db and keep the records? How could a process look like etc.